# ColdFusion Search Question/Help

Tags: search, coldfusion, if-statement

I am working on a project that is written in ColdFusion. I dont have the most knowledge when it comes to ColdFusion so I am having a small problem where we are using a CF search engine. It searches through products. Also when you browse the products it uses the same page to display the results. My problem is that it is not passing the variables into the URL for the link when you do a search, but if I browse the page it shows up. (mypage.cfm?pid=1234&m=1256 when I search it returns NULL but when I browse it returns the correct number for the manufacturer) I didnt want to post the entire code because it is a long code. So my question isn't necessarily that I want you to fix this, but can you point me in the direction of how to learn how to resolve this situation.

Comment: You are right not to post a huge amount of code, but your question is unanswerable in its current form. Isolate a small piece of code that you think should be working but isn't, and post that. While performing this process, you might find the answer yourself!

Comment: "Stanley", You need to share some of the code.  You're working as a developer and it's important to share code so we can see what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search normally from a form those variables will end up as

`form.pid` and `form.m`

when you browse via url, those variables will end up as

`url.pid` and `url.m`

You can either change your form to use `method="get"` rather than post or have code in your results page similar to this

```
<cfparam name="form.pid" default="" />
<cfparam name="form.m" default="" />
<cfparam name="url.pid" default="#form.pid#" />
<cfparam name="url.m" default="#form.m#" />
```

What this does is says, default form to nothing if its not defined
Then default url to whats in form.

The end result will have `url.pid` and `url.m` with either form or url paramaters.

This assumes that the rest of your code is using the url paramaters, which im guessing might be right as you said it works when you browse it.

Comment: If it is a scoping problem, I would recommend the first option ie using a single scope. Declaring the same variable name in multiple scopes can be confusing and sometimes leads to unintentional bugs.

Comment: In your example, `url.pid` is going to default to the literal string "form.pid". You need hashes around that variable.